# Classic ASP. Problems with calling a function

Tags: javascript, function, vbscript, asp-classic

I've written a classic ASP function that reads a MSSQL database, reads a column value and changes a image on a HTML page. Here is my code -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeiconGREEN(image) {
    document.getElementById(image).src = "./Markers/green_circle.png";
} 
function changeiconRED(image) {
    document.getElementById(image).src = "./Markers/red_circle.png";
}
function changeiconYELLOW(image) {
    document.getElementById(image).src = "./Markers/yellow_circle.png";
}
 </script> 
 <% 
Function status(atname,id)
    Dim objRecordset
    Dim DB_CONNECTIONSTRING
    Dim i
    i = 0
    set DB_CONNECTIONSTRING = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    DB_CONNECTIONSTRING = "provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQLTEST\INSTANCE01;Initial Catalog=TEST_DB;UID=wug; PWD=wug"
    Set objRecordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM Device LEFT OUTER JOIN DeviceAttribute ON DeviceAttribute.nDeviceID = Device.nDeviceID WHERE Device.bRemoved = 0 AND  DeviceAttribute.sName = N'"&atname&"'  AND DeviceAttribute.sValue LIKE N'%"&atname&"%'", DB_CONNECTIONSTRING
    Do until objRecordset.eof
        if objrecordset.fields("nWorstStateID") >= 5 and objrecordset.fields("nWorstStateID") < 7 then
        response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & vbcrlf)
        response.write("changeiconGREEN("""&id&""");" & vbcrlf)
        response.write("</script>" & vbcrlf)
   ElseIf objrecordset.fields("nWorstStateID") = 4 then
        i = 1   
   ElseIf objrecordset.fields("nWorstStateID") <= 3 and objrecordset.fields("nWorstStateID") > 7 then
        response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & vbcrlf)
        response.write("changeiconRED("""&id&""");" & vbcrlf)
        response.write("</script>" & vbcrlf)
  end if
objRecordset.movenext
 loop
  if i = 1 then
        response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & vbcrlf)
        response.write("changeiconYELLOW("""&id&""");" & vbcrlf)
        response.write("</script>" & vbcrlf)
        i=0
  end if
objRecordset.close
End Function

Call status(EDRMS,test)
%>
```

No errors are showing up, but the function doesn't seem to be working. The code works when its not in a function and the variables are taken out. Can anyone spot the problem? I've been staring at this for hours!

Comment: Take `response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & vbcrlf)`       and        `response.write("</script>" & vbcrlf)` out of function. So, it can be `response.write("<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">" & vbcrlf)    Call status(EDRMS,test)      response.write("</script>" & vbcrlf)`. This reduces clutter and it will be easier to find out. Add a alert in this script block.

Comment: Is `EDRMS` a variable or a string?

Comment: See recordset usage examples from this page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-example-vbscript    You are not using MoveFirst(), adUseClient etc. Is your connection open?

Comment: its a variable. I'm trying to call the function status with the variables atname = EDRMS and the id variable = test

Comment: @Amit Yes the connection is open.

Comment: Does my concatenation correct?

Comment: I would check the sql you're building, and make sure it's returning data. Just do a response.write of the sql out to the screen and then run it directly in your database.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery The code works if I don't use the function variables. Its something to do with the way I'm passing those variables into the function.

Comment: if you hard code the variables inside the function call, does it work? something like:  Call status("some value", "another value") if it does work, then i would ask where are you setting the values for those variables?

Comment: `No errors are showing up, but the function doesn't seem to be working` - so what is not working in the function? the javascript or the query?

Comment: @JoshMontgomery Yes the function works if I hard code the variables.

Comment: @Niladri Once I introduce variables to the function, it stops working. This must be something to do with concatenation or the variables are the wrong type.

Comment: it may be helpful if you can post the entire code. The only reason I can see why variables wouldn't work is due to the variables not getting assigned any values. better yet would be a jsFiddle (or any test url we can access) along with the full source code. Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: I found the issue! I didn't realize it needed to be case sensitive!